# how open a file exclusively with an app

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i want open a file with hp ePrint exclusively...but with my code, file is opened with adobe reader...i don't know why....
THANKS IN ADVANCE!

```
public void viewPDF() {
        String path = "/sdcard/droidText/ciccia.pdf";
try {
    File targetFile = new File(path);
    Uri targetUri = Uri.fromFile(targetFile);

    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setPackage("com.hp.android.print");
    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(targetUri, "application/pdf");

    startActivity(intent);
}catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
    final String appPackageName="com.hp.android.print";
            try{
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("market://details?id=" +appPackageName)));
            }catch(android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfer){
        startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" +appPackageName)));
    }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setPackage("com.hp.android.print")
```

**intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);**

```
intent.setDataAndType(targetUri, "application/pdf");
```

You redeclared the intent object.

Comment: i need delete this intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);?

Comment: Yes. Instead of that write this `intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);` and try.

Comment: and if i delete only this ntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)? it is same?